# How to implement single sign-on with Spring Authorization Server

Tags: oauth-2.0

Project architecture:

separation of front and back ends

Development environment:

Spring Authorization Server0.4.0
jdk 17
springboot 2.7.14

question:
No client system, they all have their own login form pages, but the login access authentication address is the same, how to achieve

Single sign-on can be successfully implemented

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.